# show hide visibility on slideshow overlay

Tags: javascript, html, css, modal-dialog, overlay

I’m doing a slideshow (via swiper), and I want to use an overlay covering the slideshow. For reasons concerning the design the overlay div has to be within the swiper container, and the link for the overlay outside this container. 
I tried using the click function, but for some reason it is not working and the overlay is not showing up. Anybody an idea how this can be fixed or what I am doing wrong? Thanks.

```js
       var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
          slidesPerView: 1,
          spaceBetween: 0,
          loop: true,
          pagination: {
            el: '.swiper-pagination',
            clickable: true,
          },
          navigation: {
            nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
            prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
          },
        });
        
        
        
    $('#test').click(function(){
      if ( $('#five-detail').css('visibility') == 'hidden' )
        $('#five-detail').css('visibility','visible');
      else
        $('#five-detail').css('visibility','hidden');
    });
```

```css
    #five-details {
      background-color:red;
      position:absolute;
      z-index:10100;   
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      visibility: hidden;
    }    
        
        
    .swiper-container {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      }
    
    .swiper-slide {
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 18px;
      background: #fff;
    
      display: -webkit-box;
      display: -ms-flexbox;
      display: -webkit-flex;
      display: flex;
      -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
      -webkit-justify-content: center;
      justify-content: center;
      -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
      -webkit-align-items: center;
      align-items: center;
      }
```

```html
<link href="https://rawgit.com/nolimits4web/Swiper/master/dist/css/swiper.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/nolimits4web/Swiper/master/dist/js/swiper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="swiper-container" id="five">
    
     <div id="five-details">
       test
     </div>
    
        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
         <div class="swiper-slide">
            <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/e2/8e/f5/e28ef573c88440fe1fdbaeb8ffa19123.jpg" width=100%/>
      </div>
         <div class="swiper-slide">
            <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5f/Wayne_campus_scienglib_900x600.jpg" width=100%/>
      </div>
         
        </div>
        
        <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
        <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
    </div>
    
    <a href="#test">DETAILS</a>
```

Comment: Can you maybe add an image of your expected result.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1st mistake 
HTML element `<a href="#test">` you are trying access this in jquery by id selector `$(#test)`
which is wrong you should change href to id like this `<a id="test">`

2nd mistake 
HTML element `<div id="five-details">` you are trying access this in jquery by id selector `$(#five-detail)` which is a typo it should be `$(#five-details)` you are missing `s`

here is the working code
https://jsfiddle.net/qhupujtk/

```js
    var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
      slidesPerView: 1,
      spaceBetween: 0,
      loop: true,
      pagination: {
        el: '.swiper-pagination',
        clickable: true,
      },
      navigation: {
        nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
        prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
      },
    });
    
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#test').click(function(){

  if ( $('#five-details').css('visibility') == 'hidden' )
    $('#five-details').css('visibility','visible');
    
  else
    $('#five-details').css('visibility','hidden');
});
    })
```

```css
#five-details {
 background-color:red;
 position:absolute;
 z-index:10100;   
 width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  visibility: hidden;
}    
    
    
.swiper-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  }

.swiper-slide {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  background: #fff;

  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://rawgit.com/nolimits4web/Swiper/master/dist/css/swiper.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/nolimits4web/Swiper/master/dist/js/swiper.min.js"></script>

<div class="swiper-container" id="five">

 <div id="five-details">
   test
 </div>

    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
     <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/e2/8e/f5/e28ef573c88440fe1fdbaeb8ffa19123.jpg" width=100%/>
  </div>
     <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5f/Wayne_campus_scienglib_900x600.jpg" width=100%/>
  </div>
     
    </div>
    
    <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
    <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
</div>

<a id="test">DETAILS</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

For first point you have used #test in href and using a click function on #test when there is no div with an id="test".

Second the id of overlay in the HTML is five-details and in Javascript is five-detail. You are missing an s in javascript section.

I have also added CSS for anchor test.

Check this JsFiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/1v2313v9/39/

```js
    var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
      slidesPerView: 1,
      spaceBetween: 0,
      loop: true,
      pagination: {
        el: '.swiper-pagination',
        clickable: true,
      },
      navigation: {
        nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
        prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
      },
    });
    
    
    
$('#test').click(function(){
  if ( $('#five-details').css('visibility') == 'hidden' )
    $('#five-details').css('visibility','visible');
  else
    $('#five-details').css('visibility','hidden');
});
```

```css
#five-details {
 background-color:red;
 position:absolute;
 z-index:10100;   
 width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  visibility: hidden;
}    

#test {
  z-index:10101;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
    
.swiper-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  }

.swiper-slide {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  background: #fff;

  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://rawgit.com/nolimits4web/Swiper/master/dist/css/swiper.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/nolimits4web/Swiper/master/dist/js/swiper.min.js"></script>
<div class="swiper-container" id="five">

 <div id="five-details">
   test
 </div>

    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
     <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/e2/8e/f5/e28ef573c88440fe1fdbaeb8ffa19123.jpg" width=100%/>
  </div>
     <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5f/Wayne_campus_scienglib_900x600.jpg" width=100%/>
  </div>
     
    </div>
    
    <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
    <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
</div>

<a id="test">DETAILS</a>
```